# AWS S3 Transfer Utility Last Modified date

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I couldn't find any information on this. Currently, I would like the app to download the image only if the Last Modified Date has been changed. This will help me to save some cost from s3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you maintain somehow the previous last modified date ? or the date you last run your program ? then you can just compare the date you last run the program if the last modified date of s3 key is more recent

Answer (score 1):

Get the object metadata as described on this AWS doc page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html
You will note that one of the items listed in the table is "Last-Modified"

The metadata can be got by calling http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectMetadataRequest.html

There is a getLastModified() method for the ObjectMetadata that ObjectMetadataRequest returns.  getLastModified() returns a Java Date object

Comment: I guess i cannot use transferUtility? And instead use AmazonS3client

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I can get the LastModified date but this changes to the date of the upload or download meaning that a copied file will always be more recent so you will end up always updating. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187847/how-to-upload-download-to-s3-without-changing-last-modified-date