# How to Upload/download to S3 without changing Last Modified date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I want to upload and download files to S3 using boto3 without changing their "LastModified" date so I can keep tabs on the age of the contents. Whenever I upload or download a file it takes on the date of this operation and I lose the date that the contents were modified.

I'm looking at the timestamp of the files using

```
fileObj.get('LastModified')
```

where the fileObj is taken from a paginator result. I'm using the following command to upload

```
s3Client.upload_fileobj(data, bucket_name, destpath)
```

and the following to download the files:

```
s3Client.download_file(bucket_name, key, localPath)
```

How can I stop the last modified date changing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible.

The Last Modified Date is generated by Amazon S3 and **cannot be overridden**.

If you wish to maintain your own timestamps, you could add some [User-Define Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) and set the value yourself.

Comment: Thanks that is usefult to know. I'll develop something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you replicate the content using the AWS replication tool from an existing bucket to another therefore the last modified date would also be replicated. It is not a copying action it is a cloning action.